# Undefined method 'id' error using collection_select with form_for in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, collection-select, undefined-function

I'm having an issue with collection_select using form_for in rails. This issue is coming from a method that was working until I namespaced my routes to be only for admin. The admin routes are working as they should as far as I can tell, but it is the only connection I can find to why this method stopped working.

Error:

```
undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x00007faf084c7048>
```

Here is the trace if that would help:

```
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:41:in `public_send'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:41:in `value'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:18:in `block in render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:18:in `fetch'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:18:in `render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:203:in `collection_select'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:835:in `collection_select'
app/views/admin/users/_edit_my_profile.html.erb:28
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `block in capture'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:209:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `capture'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1004:in `fields_for'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:2195:in `fields_for'
app/views/admin/users/_edit_my_profile.html.erb:16
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `block in capture'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:209:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:45:in `capture'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:450:in `form_for'
app/views/admin/users/_edit_my_profile.html.erb:3
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/base.rb:247:in `public_send'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/base.rb:247:in `_run'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:154:in `block in render'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:345:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:152:in `render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:285:in `block in render_partial_template'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:280:in `render_partial_template'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:271:in `render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:81:in `render_partial_to_object'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:27:in `render_to_object'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:22:in `render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:38:in `block in render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/base.rb:273:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:34:in `render'
app/views/admin/users/profile.html.erb:14
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/base.rb:247:in `public_send'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/base.rb:247:in `_run'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:154:in `block in render'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:345:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:152:in `render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `block in render_template'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:71:in `block in render_with_layout'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:70:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `render_template'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11:in `render'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:61:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:29:in `render_to_object'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:117:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/base.rb:273:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:116:in `_render_template'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:218:in `_render_template'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/home/taylor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:86:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (6.1.3.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:34:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (6.1.3.2) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (6.1.3.2) lib/action_text/engine.rb:55:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.1.3.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
actionview (6.1.3.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (6.1.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.1.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
webpacker (5.4.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.1.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:249:in `call'
puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:338:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (5.3.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Here is the full method:

```
<%= user_builder.fields_for :team_attributes, [:admin, @team] do |team_builder| %>
            <%= team_builder.hidden_field :profile, :value => "profile" %>
        <% if @company.teams.all == [] %>
            <br><h3>Create a New Team:</h3>
        Team Name: <%= team_builder.text_field :name %>
        Team Description: <%= team_builder.text_area :description %><br><br>
        <% else %>
            <% if @show_form == "new-position" %>
               Change Team: <%= team_builder.collection_select :id, @company.teams, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} %>
               Or <%= link_to "Create a new Team", "/admin/profile/#{@user.id}/edit/new-team-and-new-position" %><br><br>
            <% elsif @show_form == "new-team" %>
            <% else %>
               Change Team: <%= team_builder.collection_select :id, @company.teams, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} %>
               Or <%= link_to "Create a new Team", "/admin/profile/#{@user.id}/edit/new-team" %><br><br>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

The error is being throw here:

```
Change Team: <%= team_builder.collection_select :id, @company.teams, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} %>
```

I threw in a pry and returned the value of @company and the value of @company.teams:

```
#<Company:0x00007faf085aa668
 id: 1,
 name: "My Company",
 industry: "Retail",
 address: "1546 Jefferson Dr.",
 city: "Townesville",
 state: "AA",
 phone_number: "1232345678",
 email: "info@info.com",
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:31:22.169619000 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:31:22.169619000 UTC +00:00>

[#<Team:0x00007faf00375170
  id: 2,
  name: "Marketing",
  description:
   "Develops and implements marketing campaigns from previously developed strategies.",
  company_id: 1,
  user_id: 1,
  created_at: Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:52:15.767441000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:52:15.767441000 UTC +00:00>]
```

This is attempting to create a drop down of a company's team dependent on if the company has teams and depending on what links the user has clicked to reveal parts of the full form. Basically this error is preventing some substantial functionality and progress towards completing this application. If anyone needs more information to help please let me know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't the collection be the 3rd argument and not 2nd as you are passing? (teams) https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: If you aren't using form_for, yes. If you're using form_for the first argument is coming team_attributes https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/collection_select. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: sorry, you're right.

Comment: I just added some information that might be relevant. It's about namespacing. Joel Blum, would mind taking another look?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :/ there was no need for me to namespace @teams in fields_for when the original form_for was already namespaced. Don't go to fast people lol